# Say one wishes to transmit a sequence of characters - "ABC". What are the steps that are invariably done to enable this transmission of information?

Tags: digital-communications, encoding

I would like to elaborate on the same: Naturally, one would use the ASCII representation to first encode "ABC" into raw bits. The sequence would then become (in binary) "01000001 01000010 01000011". Let us assume that this data is transmitted in the form of a **Unipolar Encoded Signal** (between voltage levels of 0 and 5).

What are the further steps involved in transmission and reception?

*Additionally, can reception occur only real-time? In other words, can the information be picked up on the channel (can be wired or wireless) only at the same instant as when it was transmitted? Isn't there a chance that there might be some other data being transmitted at the same frequency (at the instance of time we are trying to detect/receive)?*

To summarize, how do we know that the information we receive is actually the information that we are meant to receive? Do the concepts of Synchronisation and Equalisation help solve this problem?

Comment: Learn a bit about *communication protocols*. In particular about the physical layer. It is way too broad for this site.

Comment: "*Isn't there a chance that there might be some other data being transmitted at the same frequency*" if it's a full-duplex wired communication between only two nodes, no. Otherwise, certainly yes, but maybe no, depending on the arbitration schemes of the upper layers of the protocol. There are also checksums that are usually sent within frames to solve some of the problems you mention. Hard to be more specific than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is too complicated for **any** engineer to handle. That's why we divide communications into **layers**.

The bottom layer is invariably the physical layer, voltages on cables, or radio signals in the air.

The top layer is the application, 'let's send 'ABC' to Fred'.

In between are half a dozen layers that handle collisions with other data, addressing, error correction, no loss of data, no duplication of data, making the data arrive in the right order, make sure the data goes to the right place, talk ASCII or unicode, make sure any bad guys can't see the data, etc.

Generally we actively engineer one layer, use the services of the layer below, and provide services to the layer above. Then we can get our head around what's going on.